# Properties Dialog in EA

Tags: enterprise-architect

1. Is there any Event in EA that is triggered when the properties dialog in EA is opened and when it is closed.
2. Can we get the instance of the properties dialog.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `EA_OnContextItemChanged` to catch property dialog openings. See also the related `EA_OnContextItemDoubleClicked` and `EA_OnNotifyContextItemModified` operations in the [EA help](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/automation_and_scripting/context_item_events.html)
2. Not from EA's API. You would need to go through the Windoze handles, though I have no idea what you want to do with that.